# Perl push function gives index values instead of array elements

Tags: arrays, perl

I am reading a text file named, mention-freq, which has data in the following format:

```
1

1

13

2
```

I want to read the lines and store the values in an array like this: `@a=(1, 1, 13, 2)`. The Perl push function gives the index values/line numbers, i.e., 1,2,3,4, instead of my desired output. Could you please point out the error? Here is what I have done:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FH, "<mention-freq") || die "$!";
my @a;
my $line;
while ($line = <FH>)
{
    $line =~ s/\n//;
    push @a, $line;
    print @a."\n";
}
close FH;
```

Comment: I like `twoHandsTwoCutsFunction` function :) `sub{map{s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; $_}@_}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bug is that you are printing the concatenation of `@a` and a newline.  When you concatenate, that forces scalar context.  The scalar sense of an array is not its contents but rather its element count.

You just want

```
 print "@a\n";
```

instead.

Also, while it will not affect your code here, the normal way to remove the record terminator read in by the `<>` readline operator is using `chomp`:

```
chomp $line;
```